# Get data from table only id 2 data

Tags: php, sql

i hava a table

```
id   sentUID    recUID   Amount
1       1         2       100
2       2         1       100
3       4         2       100
4       2         1       100
5       8         6       100
6       2         9       100
```

and i want to get userID 2 record like this

```
id   sentUID    recUID   Amount
1       1         2       100
3       4         2       100
6       2         9       100
```

only three UserID 1, 4, 9 sent or recive amount.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly your problem is can you show us some code? Maybe it will be clearer for us to help.

Comment: How come Id=6 is in the output and not id=4. what is the logic???

Comment: I think Habib wants rows with a unique UID that appears with 2, not depending on whether that is a recUID or a sentUID.  Since 2 appears with 1, 4, and 9, he wants 3 rows total, the rows should be a row where 2 appears with 1, 4 or 9, and not repeating these. So row 4 is not needed as we already have a row with 2.

Comment: admittedly, this is a somewhat unusual request.  Normally, we would treat sentUID and recUID as different and the query posted in the answer by Gordon Linoff would be correct.

Comment: In my previous comment, the last sentence should be "So row 4 is not needed as we already have a row with 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE id IN 
(SELECT tab1.mId FROM
  (SELECT MIN(id) as mId, CASE WHEN sentUID=2 THEN recUID
                               WHEN recUID=2  THEN sentUID 
                          END AS person
   FROM data WHERE recUID=2 OR sentUID=2
   GROUP BY person)
 AS tab1);
```

result:

```
id   sentUID    recUID   Amount
1       1         2       100
3       4         2       100
6       2         9       100
```

the intermediate table `tab1` lists each of the unique UIDs that appear with 2 and is used to calculate the final result:

```
mId       person
1          1
3          4
6          9
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f6a5/13/0

Comment: Thank you soo much.. <3 it work..

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where 2 in (sentUID, recUID)
order by id;
```

Comment: No, i dont want all records, just i want to get who sent or recive amount to userID 2

Comment: @HabibHaider . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: This query show all rows..